# Azure DevOps | TFS | Rest API | power shell script to get latest changeset description of git repository

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

Does anyone has power shell script to call Azure DevOps API in order to get latest changeset description of git repository?

Comment: Please provide an example of a solution you've attempted to implement and let us know what issue you're having with your solution. You will not find people to implement a full solution for you on Stack Overflow; you will find people willing to **help** you implement **your** solution.

Answer (score -1):

For git repositories, it should be a commit and not a changeset. If you want to get the latest commit comments from a specific git repository, then you can try the following PowerShell script to call the REST API ([Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#examples)):

```
Param(
[string]$collectionurl = “https://dev.azure.com/{organization}", #Or specific TFS collection url
[string]$project = “ProjectName”,
[string]$repoid = “e7ad43eb-ecad-4098-93b4-b63fdf88711a”, #The specific git repository ID.
[string]$user = “”,
[string]$token = “PAT”
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$searchCriteria = "$" + "top=1"

$Url = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoid/commits?searchCriteria.$searchCriteria&api-version=5.0"  
    
$commit = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
cls
$commit.value | select commitId, comment,url
```

[image]